# How to open Apple Store instead of iTunes store in Xamarin forms iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a Xamarin forms application and I am checking for the store update in the app start.
If an app update is available I am redirecting to **"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-name/id?mt=8"** but this will open the iTunes store, but I need to redirect to Apple Store. Is there any way to achieve this?

Or Provide me with the link to open Apple Store instead of the iTunes app

Answer (score 3):

#### The format of the standard App Store links

`https://itunes.apple.com/<location>/app/<appName>/<id>?mt=8`

For example: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8

#### The format of the Short App Store Links

- **Company Name**

  `http://appstore.com/<companyname>`

  For example: http://appstore.com/apple
- **App Name**

  `http://appstore.com/<appname>`

  For example: http://appstore.com/keynote
- **App by Company**

  `http://appstore.com/<companyname>/<appname>`

  For example: http://appstore.com/apple/keynote

In Forms you can open App store using   `Launcher.TryOpenAsync(url);`

Check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1633/_index.html.

Comment: May I know if it works for you ? If you have any problem please let me know.

Comment: Do you have any links similar to this "itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-name/id?mt=8itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-name/id?mt=8"? that will directly open the AppStore instead of iTunes?