# How to open a Play store or App store from link in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, app-store

In Xamarin by using App linking we can open the app from an email link. If the App is not installed means how to open the App Store or Play Store?

Thanks in Advance,
Raj Kumar G

I am able to open the app from an email invite if the app is not there means it is redirected to the browser.

So what I am expecting is instead of redirecting to the browser it should redirect to App Store or Play Store.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934822/how-to-open-apple-store-instead-of-itunes-store-in-xamarin-forms-ios-app